# Error call.enqueue in Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I use Retrofit simple
I have Error in  Call"<"EmployeesModel">"

And MyApplictaion With Run it Showed  Stop Appliction Messaged
MySource:

```
 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://www.mocky.io/v2/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
```

And Server Source:

```
 //Server
    Call<EmployeesModel> call = service.getEmployees();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<EmployeesModel>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<EmployeesModel> call, Response<EmployeesModel> response) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<EmployeesModel> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

And My interface Source

```
 public interface APIService {

    @GET("569ce520110000fb2dce7655")
    Call<EmployeesModel> getEmployees();
}
```

Comment: Wow, I forgot to give permission to connect to the Internet<br>
My problem is Sloved with <br>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `EmployeesModel` model with below one and also add another model class named `Employee`

**`EmployeesModel.java`**

```
    public class EmployeesModel {

@SerializedName("employees")
@Expose
private List<Employee> employees = null;

public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
return employees;
}

public void setEmployees(List<Employee> employees) {
this.employees = employees;
}

}
```

**`Employee.java`**

```
    public class Employee {

@SerializedName("firstName")
@Expose
private String firstName;
@SerializedName("lastName")
@Expose
private String lastName;

public String getFirstName() {
return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
this.lastName = lastName;
}

}
```

and then try to access data like this(example shows accessing the key - `firstName`)

```
@Override
    public void onResponse(Call<EmployeesModel> call, Response<EmployeesModel> response) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "OK, firstName :"+response.body().getFirstName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: I Replace you're code,But My App Stoped again<br/> Error is for this line( call.enqueue(new Callback<EmployeesModel>())

Comment: Wow, I forgot to give permission to connect to the Internet<br>
My problem is sloved with <br>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>